# Facebook connect 403 Access Denied

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the Facebook JavaScript SDK for a project I'm currently working on. It's been working fine before, but when I opened it today, the URL http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js is not accessible. When I inspected the network using Firebug, I noticed that the server was returning 403 Access Denied.

Is there something I am getting wrong or is it Facebook server problem?

Comment: It's working fine for me here, are you sure it's not a proxy server or firewall between your server and Facebook that's causing the problem?

Comment: I think it's the particular server I'm using or my network. I'm connecting to a server located in Europe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out that Facebook's new HTTPS feature is interfering. Using https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js solves the problem. Seems someone misconfigured their servers.